# boost mapped_file_sink append to the end of a file when file is not large enough

Tags: c++, boost

I want to use `boost::iostreams::mapped_file_sink` to write a logger.

I first create a mapped_file which is 4KB; When the file is full and the program is trying to write the 4K+1 Byte, I enlarge the mapped_file_param's size, reopen the "same file", but set the mapped_param.offset = 4KB. Then I write into the memory where the .data() returns.

Now  the problem is that when I want to append the 4K+1 Byte data into the file at the 4K+1 position, the file's previous 4KB data is erased! I only have the (4K+1)^th data in the file!

Can anyone help me?

[UPDATE]: Below is my program:

```
void read_write_unidirection_example()
{

        boost::iostreams::mapped_file_sink file_sink;
        boost::iostreams::mapped_file_params param_sink;
        int offset = 0;
        int page;
        bool restart = true;
        param_sink.path = "result.log";
        param_sink.offset = 0;
        param_sink.new_file_size = file_sink.alignment(); /*This has to be the size of bytes to write!*/
        file_sink.open(param_sink);
        std::cout<<param_sink.new_file_size<<std::endl;
        if( ! file_sink.is_open()) 
                return;

        for(int i=0; i<4000; i++)
        {   
                std::stringstream ss;
                ss<<"LOG ********"<<i<<"-"<<offset<<"*********\n";
                int slen = strlen(ss.str().c_str()); 
                //                std::cout<<i<<" "<<offset<<"+"<<slen<<"="<<offset+slen<<" "<<(offset + slen > param_sink.new_file_size)<<"|"; 
                if(offset + slen > file_sink.alignment())
                {
                        std::cout<<"Exceed memory limit @"<<i<<" "<<offset<<"+"<<slen<<std::endl;
                        file_sink.close();
                        page += 1;
                        offset = 0;
                        param_sink.offset = param_sink.new_file_size;
                        param_sink.new_file_size += file_sink.alignment();
                        std::cout<<"file.offset: "<<param_sink.offset<<" file.size: "<<param_sink.new_file_size<<std::endl;
                        file_sink.open(param_sink);
                        if(!file_sink.is_open()) return;
                        std::cout<<"new mapped_file created!"<<std::endl;
                        restart = true;
                }
                char * pointer= file_sink.data()+offset;
                if(restart) 
                {
                        std::cout<<(void*)file_sink.data()<<"+"<<offset<<" = "<<(void*)pointer<<std::endl; 

                }
                memcpy(pointer, ss.str().c_str(), slen);
                if(restart){
                        std::cout<<"hehe"<<std::endl;
                        restart = false;
                }
                offset += slen;
        }
        file_sink.close();
}
```

I want to append to the result.log file everytime when this file is reopened. The result.log is supposed to service as a log file.

Comment: Some code might help.

Comment: Parameter "new_file_size" will cause an overwrite on open if it is not 0.  Ref:  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html#mapped_file_sink

Comment: Hi @DNT, Thank you very much for your reply! But if I set the new_file_size to 0, will the file's size increase when I write more data? I tried, but the file's size never increase. :(

Comment: You might want to try re-sizing the file by one more increment of alignment before you open it, and then open it with new_file_size=0; This should map the entire file with its current, increased size.

Comment: Hi @DNT, your suggestion should be workable. But the issue is performance. I want to use this as an efficient logger. If I remap the whole enlarged file, the memory is not used efficiently. Do you have any insight?

Comment: I see what you are trying to do. This technique provides fast access within the bounds of the current log space until you reach the upper limit. Then you need to expand it, and you say this is too expensive for your application. There is always a trade-off, so you might want to consider an asynchronous file logger in a different thread, that accepts fixed size packets in a input queue, then logs them without delaying your work thread(s). Your logging in this way, decays down to simply sending each message to the input queue of the logger using an appropriate synchronization mechanism.

Comment: P.S. I have used this technique with a threaded window logger that logs to a MS Windows editbox (very slow). However, the main thread suffers a very small overhead when the threaded implementation is active. If I use direct logging to the window logger without the thread ... things get slow :)

Comment: HI @DNT, Thank you so much for sharing your experience! I see the design and think it should work! I will have a try:-)

Comment: Thanks Mike Xu. I hope my idea is suitable for a logger within your parameters. If it turns out that it is, let me know so I can re-post it as an answer :)

Comment: Yes! it is suitable and smart! Please post it as an answer:-)